# openshift not working database connection

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0, openshift

I'm experiencing issues connecting to mysql in the Openshift platform. I have this site http://studentinfobook-rrubio.rhcloud.com/showing errors. It's a cakephp very simple app, that apparently can't connect to mysql cartridge. But if i attempt connect directly to mysql in the command line like:

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

then it's connecting very well. The same connecting w/ phpmyadmin. Do you think it's something w/ cakephp (this app is working locally), or something i still have to do in openshift?

Thanks in advance...

EDIT

There is not too much code to be written. This is my database.php file in [/var/lib/openshift/548f654a4382ec3b58000078/app-root/repo/app/Config]:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => DB_HOST,
            'port' => DB_PORT,
            'login' => DB_USER,
            'password' => DB_PASS,
            'database' => DB_NAME,
            'prefix' => ''
            //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

As i said this returns from mysql the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

But perfectly worked when connecting from the command line or phpmyadmin with the supplied credentials...

Comment: Please write code where site create connection.

Answer (score 0):

That error message usually seems to mean that the socket is not available to use for connecting to the mysql server.  Are you using a scaled application? if so, then there is no socket to use since the mysql database is on another gear.   Here is a sample connection file from a cakephp-example that runs on openshift currently: https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-example/blob/master/php/app/Config/database.php

You can see if that helps you with your issue.